# Adding complete css and files from materializecss on Yii2

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

after my latest question about adding it in `Yii2`, here is my AppAsset:

```
<?php
/**
 * @link http://www.yiiframework.com/
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2008 Yii Software LLC
 * @license http://www.yiiframework.com/license/
 */

namespace frontend\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

/**
 * @author Qiang Xue <qiang.xue@gmail.com>
 * @since 2.0
 */
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/materialize.css',
        'css/materialize.min.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/materialize.js',
        'js/materialize.min.js',
    ];
    public $depends = [
        # 'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        # 'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];


}
```

And this is the structure of those files i've added before.:

[image]

**as you can see, i've just added css`s and js files without font and icons.**

So, what should i do else?

**the template is a little bit like materialize, but still i think it's has a problem, see:**

[image]

if there are many things to do, please guide me to do this and let it go.

also, it was on the view:

```
use common\widgets\Alert;
use frontend\assets\AppAsset;
use yii\bootstrap\Nav;
use yii\bootstrap\NavBar;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\Breadcrumbs;

AppAsset::register($this);
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Frist uncoment the 'yii\web\YiiAsset' and second use only the min version of the css and js, and add in your app asset css 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons'

And the last your nav bar need to be something like that

```
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="brand-logo">my company</a>
    <a href="#" data-activates="mobile" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
    <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li><a href="<?= Url::toRoute("site/index")?>">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?= Url::toRoute("site/stuff")?>">Stuffs</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile">
     <li><a href="<?= Url::toRoute("site/index")?>">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="<?= Url::toRoute("site/stuff")?>">Stuffs</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Other easy way to do this is installing materialize css theme for yii2 using composer :)